# How do I write to a file without erasing the previous line?

Tags: java

Everytime I re-ask the user to enter their grades, I have it write a string to the file gradeReport, but everytime the while loop repeats, the previous result is erased. HOw do I get several lines outputted in the file?

```
//Open file and call writeToFile method        
         PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter("gradeReport.txt");
         outputFile.println(s.writeToFile());
         outputFile.close();
```

And the method:

```
public String writeToFile() 
    { 
     DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        String str= name + "--" + id + "--" + f.format(getPercentage())+ "--" + getGrade();
      return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the PrintWriter around a FileWriter that is set to append to the file.

```
PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("gradeReport.txt", true));
```

- Note 1: the FileWriter constructor's second parameter of true means that it is set to append to the file rather than to over-write the file.
- Note 2: this question will likely and appropriately be closed soon as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the constructor 
     FileWriter(String filename, boolean append)
to open the file in append mode.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);
```